# What is the best way to download mulitple images using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, object

I have a section in which I have multiple images now on click I would like to download all.

Here is what  my images look like

[image]

and here is how I am downloading those images using jquery

HTML

```
<button class="button" onclick="downloadImages()">Download</button>
```

JS

```
function downloadImages(){
    let link =  $(".grcode-image");
    console.log('link', link)
    link.click();
}
```

When I click the download button only I see is the console log

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? and what do I need to do to be able to download all images at once?

Comment: Please use text rather than images of text to show data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need download the images without zip:

Just map the array and click:

```
function downloadImages() {
    $(".grcode-image").each(function (index, currentElement) {
      currentElement.click();
    });
  }
```

Comment: weird i get this error when I click download `Uncaught TypeError: links.forEach is not a function
    at downloadImages (code.html:351:23)`

Comment: use `.each` and let me know if work for you.

Comment: now I get this error `Uncaught TypeError: link.click is not a function` when i use each

Comment: give me the console.log of `link` inside the each

Comment: still the same error

Comment: it shows zero : linkss 0

Comment: I solved the problem I used querySelectorAll and the foreach, but now it downloads only ten images instead of the 50 images that I have in this section , do you know why only ten images are downloaded instaead of all 50 ?

Comment: I modify the answer with the right way using each

Comment: When I used firefox it downloaded all the images but chrome only 10

Comment: in chrome you have to enable the popup here chrome://settings/content/popups

Comment: For avoiding this problem I recommend you use something like zip